# Android Studio debugging inconsistency

Tags: android, xml, debugging

I'm not sure this is a common issue, I have Android studio installed on my window pc and my mac laptop and on and off I will switch between both.

Just now I was cleaning up my source code and delete a `.xml` file from the layout folder and I debug using my phone to make sure it is a working before I upload to the server for other programmers to access it.

Later on the programmers said that there are errors in my file and ask me to look into it, so I immediately switch to my mac and try to debug it and I got the error as well. Later found out that I didn't remove the activity call from `AndroidManifest.xml` for the previous deleted `.xml`.

To make sure I did not get the wrong version of my build I try again on my window pc with the errors and perform debugging and surprisingly there isn't any error and the emulator run smoothly. How is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

[do you use version control](http://wii.logdown.com/posts/2013/11/15/android-studio-git-tutorial) aka team, git, [subversion](https://weeklyitblogs.wordpress.com/2015/01/15/subversion-with-android-studio/) vcs. I believe android studio does this automaticaly via vcs on main menu. github[is another form of this](https://github.com/) concept. When a team works together it is common to have a local copy of source code and a remote repository on a server. You also may have different branches or versions of the local and/or remote source code. If you find out what version control you use and you still need help post a comment back.

[By the way](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html) android studio is now using gradle so you can now have free and paid flavors of the same app and i can see that could cause problems.